# passing positional parameters to bash function that contain a `.` dot

Tags: bash, syntax, quotes, double-quotes, ifs

I have a function in bash

```
foo ()
{
     # does some work
}
```

and I pass a parameter that contains a dot (for example hostnames contain dots)

```
HOSTNAME=`hostname` # pretend its host.on.a.net
foo $HOSTNAME
```

When `foo` does work on `HOSTNAME`, it will split into multiple arguments and `$1` will be `host` instead of the full `host.on.a.net`

How do I avoid this default behavior?

Comment: Double-quote the variable reference (`foo "$HOSTNAME"`). Also, it sounds like you changed `IFS`; if you do that, you should set it back to normal ASAP to avoid weird effects like this. Also, `HOSTNAME` is a standard pre-set variable. If you want its standard value, just use it; otherwise, use another name (preferably lower- or mixed-case, do avoid problems like this). BTW, [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) will spot many common mistakes like the quoting issue; I highly recommend it.

Comment: I did change `IFS` within a script but isn't that bounded by the scope of the script? I also removed that code within the script. Anyways, I added the quotes and it solved the problem. My god...I can't believe it was all due to that... smh...

Comment: Not double-quoting vars and changing `IFS` are both kind of risky; doing both is almost certain to cause trouble.

Comment: not double quoting is a convention? Bash should just do it by default if its risky behavior. IFS was part of another SO... oh well...

Comment: The original unix shell would word-split any unquoted variable references (and command substitutions and...) based on `IFS` because it seemed like a useful feature at time. Over the years it's become clear that this default is actually a bad idea, but most shells still maintain this behavior for compatibility (zsh is the exception). So... experienced shell scripters learn to double-quote, to avoid trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the shellcheck website. I'm using it and the pointers are very useful.